# Cached js file Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, amazon-cloudfront

I have a javascript file in s3 and served by cloudfront cache. 
But sometime it starts showing

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

in the console and does not load at all.

[image]

But when I open the same url in incognito window it works just fine. This js file is generated by [react create app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) and file size is 2.05MB.

**Update**
The problem looks like with **service worker**. because content type of js file is set as text/html when being returned from cache. On seeing this browser tried to render the js and fails. Even the content of the file is different than expected, instead of js file my index.html is being returned. But how can wrong file be cached??[image]